# Updating an app build after expiration in TestFlight

Tags: xcode, testflight, apple-developer

I need to update a build because it has been expired, without any change in the codes and script of the app. Do I need to create a Distributions Certificate, App ID, and Provisioning Profile? It’s my first time doing apple developer tasks. What exactly should I do for just updating it the build?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 14, there is an option where you can send up an existing archive, and have the store remap the build number to prevent a conflict.

To the fastest possible solution would be to find the old archive on the old Xcode install, and re-load it from there (and let App Store Connect resolve the build number conflict).

(I assume this is a use case of this feature, in the "old days", you had to increment the build number and re-build and re-distribute properly to get a new build in TestFlight. Without good branching/tagging in GIT, some groups were doomed when TF expired).